# Is there any API for Python that returns translations in JSON?

Tags: python, android, api, kivy, translation

So I'm making an Android app with [`Kivy`](https://www.kivy.org), [`KivyMD`](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io), and Python code that translates text from any language to any language. I used the [`googletrans`](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) module in Python for the translations. It's a Python API for translating text. It does exactly what [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) does. It searches already translated documents on the internet and finds similar phrases to the phrase the user wants to translate. Then, it returns the results it found. I'm actually thinking it gets the results back in JSON format and then picks the best result and returns it to the user. Because a few days ago when I was using this module, I got a JSONDecodeError. So my question is: Is there any website that returns translations in JSON format so that I can instead just get the translations with the [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) module?

Comment: Can you explain further what the error is?

Comment: There is no error. I was just wondering if there was any API for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown here https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text, you can use the google translation API to receive your results in json format. You should create a file called `request.json` (either automatically through python, or manually) that contains the following, where `target` is the language to translate to, and `q` is a list of phrases to translate:

```
{
  "q": ["Hello world", "My name is Jeff"],
  "target": "de"
}
```

You can then run the following terminal command to retrieve the `json` file, and then parse that in python.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2
```

If you want to run this from python, you can use the `subprocess` module, or follow the guide on the website to run this from python (https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#translate_translate_text-python)